# Testing in a modular/pluggable database-backed application framework

Tags: database, testing, plugins, orm, frameworks

## Context

Currently working with a modular database-backed application framework: the data store is a thin layer over a regular Postgres, and modules/plugins can depend on one another and perform relatively arbitrary operations on said database including adding columns or changing their properties (e.g. make a dependency's column NOT NULL), so enabling a module consists of

1. applying its DDL (new tables, new columns, new constraints, new indexes, alterations to existing versions of any of the previous, ...)
2. installing any "static" data it contains
3. optionally running its tests

## Problem

This leads to *testing* being a chore, the current system has to install a module then run its tests before it can proceed to the next module, and this requires essentially resetting the system to 0 in order to re-run tests (as a module K may have modified the DB schema in such a way that module J's tests don't run anymore). It is heavyweight, bothersome, slow, and difficult to integrate to existing testing tools or meta-tools.

## Query

I have been looking into making this less inconvenient, but aside from skipping modules (the current system has no notion of "modules to test", only "modules to install", and upon trying to test a module it will also run tests for all of its dependencies) I have not managed to come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you keep the changes inside one schema it should be easy (unless i didn't understand your requirements properly). before each test you should reset the database. one simple idea would be to drop and create the schema again. if you need to reset db to some predefined state, check postgres templates. if your tool should allow completely custom db operations like deleting users or schemas, then you'll need some kind of abstraction layer that keeps track of how to connect to this db after all those changes (user, passwd, jdbc url).

most of existing projects for integration testing are not designed to test schema changes but rather to test how code cooperates with fixed schema.

i don't know any other project that provides all you need, so it will be a shameless marketing. recently i created a tool for integration testing [testegration](https://github.com/piotrturski/testegration). it's a commercial product but has a free tier. it was also designed to test a fixed schema but it should handle your case - just override the 'reset' phase to use drop/create schema or using postgres template